# How to add a single caption under an array of plots?

Tags: r, plot

Based on the solutions of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31989130/6574038) I'm looking for a way to add a caption.

```
par(mfrow=c(2, 2), oma=c(2, 2, 0, 0)+0.1)

lapply(unique(iris$Species), function(x) 
  with(iris[iris$Species == x, ], 
       plot(Sepal.Length, type="l", col="orange", ylab="", xlab=x)))
mtext("Index", side=1, outer=TRUE)
mtext("Sepal.Length", side=2, outer=TRUE)
text(1, 1, "my caption")  # no effect
```

The result should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: what about another `mtext` call: `mtext("my caption", side=1, outer=TRUE, adj=0)`

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for, I hadn't figured out the `adj=0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a caption using `mtext`, and align the text to the left hand side using the `adj` argument (for `side=1`, "adj=0 means left alignment")

So you can use

```
mtext("my caption", side=1, outer=TRUE, adj=0)
```

You can add a bit of vertical distance between the caption and the x-axis using the `line` argument, although the amount of distance will be limited by the relevant `oma` parameter.

For example, with

```
par(oma=c(4, 2, 0, 0)+0.1)
```

You can use place the caption three lines below the axis title using `line=3`

```
mtext(~italic("my caption"), side=1, outer=TRUE, adj=0, line=3)
```